# How create okhttp with ssl certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have created 2 classes:
-This one extend OkHttp and have a new method getUnsafeOkHttpClient().

```
public class GetExampleOkHttp extends OkHttpClient {
    public OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }
                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }
                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
                }
            } };
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And other Main class:

```
class ExampleOkHttpMain  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        GetExampleOkHttp example = new GetExampleOkHttp();          
        example.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

             Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://lachuzhnikov.kiev.ua/test.txt")
                .build();
            Response response = example.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.body().string());       
    }
}
```

But I still have an error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>         at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)

Answer (score -1):

1: Download https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/ 
2: Open firefox and go to page and export cer 
3: Backup Java\jdk....\jre\lib\security\cacerts (eg: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security) 
4: Copy cacerts to another folder 
5: Portecle open file cacerts (pass: changeit) import cer in step 2 and save 
6: Copy and replace new cacerts Java\jdk....\jre\lib\security\cacerts